# I am unable to refactor my code for reusability

Tags: javascript

I want to extract the call back function into a separate function so I can reuse it without  typing manually wherever I need to use it but am unable to achieve the desired result. pls I need help am just new to javascript . Below is my my attempt and the main code.

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
const registerSection = document.querySelector('.register-section');
const loginSection = document.querySelector('.login-section');
const aboutUsSection = document.querySelector('.about-us-section');

const showForm = function (e, cl) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains(`${cl}`)) return;

  loginSection.classList.add('hide-section');
  aboutUsSection.classList.add('hide-section');
  registerSection.classList.remove('hide-section');
};

nav.addEventListener('click', showForm.bind('list-link-register'));
nav.addEventListener('click', showForm.bind('list-link-login'));


// This is the code I wanted to refactor

nav.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('list-link-register')) return;

  loginSection.classList.add('hide-section');
  aboutUsSection.classList.add('hide-section');
  registerSection.classList.remove('hide-section');
});

nav.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('list-link-login')) return;

  aboutUsSection.classList.add('hide-section');
  registerSection.classList.add('hide-section');
  loginSection.classList.remove('hide-section');
});
```

Comment: You can't put in a single function how you would want as there is a difference in behaviour where `registerSection` and `loginSection` have reversed `add/remove` between the 2 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an `if` statement you could put both cases in the same function

```
nav.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

  if (e.target.classList.contains('list-link-register')){
      aboutUsSection.classList.add('hide-section');
      registerSection.classList.add('hide-section');
      loginSection.classList.remove('hide-section');
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains('list-link-login')) {
      loginSection.classList.add('hide-section');
      aboutUsSection.classList.add('hide-section');
      registerSection.classList.remove('hide-section');
  }
});
```